# Windows Batch recursive delete old files

Tags: windows, batch

I'm looking for a function in batch that recursive delets all files/folders older than X Days from a given path.

Is there a Fast and easy snippet that could be placed in a batch function?

Comment: possibly duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51054/batch-file-to-delete-files-older-than-n-days

Comment: also: http://serverfault.com/questions/49614/delete-files-older-than-x-days (maybe we need one of those on SU as well...)

Comment: hmm on serverfault these are not really batch.
stackoverflow are nor running for me atm. but I need to figure out the problem ...

Answer (score 1):

If your command interpreter is [JP Software's TCC/LE](http://jpsoft.com./tccle_cmd_replacement.html), simply use [date ranges](http://jpsoft.com./help/dateranges.htm) and the [`del`](http://jpsoft.com./help/del.htm) command.  Here's how to delete files (and consequent empty directories) older than 30 days:

```
del /[d-30,%@makedate[0]] /s/x *
```

The `*` is a wildcard, of course, and can include a pathname.

### Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2003,2007). [*Performing some commonly desired tasks with JP Software's command interpreters.*](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/common-tasks-with-jpsoft-clis.html). Frequently Given Answers.

Comment: I can only use the standard Windows batch interpreter.